# ACCESS DENIED error from stream file open

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, filestream

I have create my code in order to write images in a remote sql server

All the details of accessing and writing are fine until now, including the system account right now i'm in the command of:

```
SqlFileStream = New SqlFileStream(filePathName, fileToken, FileAccess.Write)
```

and when i'm trying to execute it the Server returns the error 'Access denied' I have try all the posible ( those which i know) combinations to overcome this error but nothing Please give me the best assistance you may have

I've put a sniffer in my PC to lookup the packages between Server and my PC, so here what i got: the first addres is the Server address and the second is my PC address.

*"10.93.1.29","10.93.1.10","SMB","Tree Connect AndX Request, Path: \DEVELOPER\SQLEXPRESS "

"10.93.1.10","10.93.1.29","SMB","Tree Connect AndX Response"

"10.93.1.29","10.93.1.10","SMB","Trans2 Request, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Query File Basic Info, Path: \v1\RemoteDB\dbo\tPImages\tPImages_Image\DB6F1B11-2FAF-4326-8E44-FBA71DA94CEC\b8010a0f1aaf47c1888aab2e830dff43"

"10.93.1.10","10.93.1.29","SMB","Trans2 Response, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Error: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED"

"10.93.1.29","10.93.1.10","SMB","NT Trans Request, NT CREATE"

"10.93.1.10","10.93.1.29","SMB","NT Trans Response, NT CREATE, FID: 0x0000, Error: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED"*

I dare to say that this error comes from the Windows program when the SQL 2008 tries to write some DATA to the filies which creates on C:\sqlRemData..... (but finally i'm not sure even for that)

PLEASE if anyone knows?

Comment: It would be helpful if you presented your code (i.e. where the arguments are coming from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
     public static bool SetAcl(string filename, string account) 
{ 
    FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow); 

    PermissionSet fp = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted); 
    fp.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { filename })); 
    fp.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, new string[] { filename })); 
    fp.Assert(); 

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)); 


    bool what = false; 
    DirectorySecurity security = di.GetAccessControl(); 

    security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, rule, out what); 
    di.SetAccessControl(security); 
    return what; 

}
```

Comment: With this i change the security level from the account i use?
and when you say filename what exactly you mean?
And Please can you give this in VB.NET and not in C?
Do I have to made any Import in my code?
Have in mind that in my code snippet take place some other actions except the image writing so please don't confuse.
At the end is the istruction i care for.
Thank you in advance
I'm posting for you my code

Comment: HI Leferis,
file name is the filePathName 
SqlFileStream = New SqlFileStream(filePathName, fileToken, FileAccess.Write) 

So your filePathname ACL must be set with an account that has Write/Directory browsing permissisons.

Unfortunately I have not coded in VB;

Comment: My God dear Tony
I'm using the DOMAIN\Administrator with all the permissions open on the server and steel return me 'Access Denied'
--------
but the truth is that i haven't use your code yet because my mother died and i was run for this issue so i will start this week again 
----------------
and i'm thing: If all these problems are in my local server what will happen in my ISP server how should i found the proper account to do my job?
?-?-?-?-?_

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Sub WriteFileStream(ByVal imSource As Byte(), ByVal imSize As Integer, ByVal imTy As Type, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim subProvider As String = Nothing
    Dim subDataSource As Object = Nothing
    Dim subUid As String = Nothing
    Dim subPwd As String = Nothing
    Dim subDataBase As String = Nothing
    Dim subPSI As Boolean = Nothing
    Dim ParamXML() As String = Nothing
    Dim TypeOfServer As String = "Remote"
    Dim imParam(3) As String
    Dim imTable(1) As String
    Dim RemoteSQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    Dim tokenReader As SqlDataReader
    '-------------------------------------------------'

    Dim AbsRecord As Int64 = 0
    Dim VarString(10) As String
    Dim VarInt(10) As Integer
    '-------------------------------------------------'
    ParamXML = Split(loadXmlFile(TypeOfServer, sender, e), "|")
    subUid = ParamXML(3)
    subProvider = ParamXML(0)
    subDataSource = ParamXML(1)
    subDataBase = ParamXML(2)
    subPwd = ParamXML(4)
    subPSI = ParamXML(5)

    Dim SchemaID As String = Convert.ToInt16(ParamXML(8))
    Dim SchemaName As String = Nothing
    If SchemaID = 1 Then
        SchemaName = subUid
    ElseIf SchemaID = 2 Then
        SchemaName = "dbo"
    ElseIf SchemaID = 0 Then
        SchemaName = "dbo"
    End If
    '-------------------------------------------------'
    imTable(0) = "tPDetails"
    imTable(1) = "tPImages"
    Try
        imParam(0) = Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim.ToString     'Name'
        imParam(1) = Me.TextBox2.Text.Trim.ToString     'Code'
        imParam(2) = Me.TextBox3.Text.Trim.ToString     'Price'
        imParam(3) = Me.TextBox4.Text.Trim.ToString     'Comments'
        '========================================================'
    If RemoteSQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then RemoteSQLConn.Close()
    SQL_Connection(TypeOfServer, TypeOfServer & "Conn.xml", sender, e)
    RemoteSQLConn.open()

        '----------------------'
        Dim imHolder As Image = Image.FromStream(imStream)
        Dim imHeight As Integer = imHolder.Height
        Dim imWidth As Integer = imHolder.Width
        Dim imLength As Integer = imHolder.PropertyItems.Length
        Dim imType As Type = imTy
        '----------------------'
        Dim FirstColumnNames As String = _
                                imTable(0) & "_Code, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Price, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Title, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Type, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Height, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Width, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Stock, " & _
                                imTable(0) & "_Comments "
        Dim FirstFieldsValues As String = "'" & imParam(1) & "', '" & _
                                imParam(2) & "', '" & _
                                imParam(0) & "', '" & _
                                imType.ToString & "', '" & _
                                imHeight & "', '" & _
                                imWidth & "', '" & _
                                "0', '" & _
                                imParam(3) & "' "
'--------------------------------------------'
           RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & _
    SchemaName & "." & imTable(0) & " (" & FirstColumnNames & ")                     VALUES (" & FirstFieldsValues & ") ", RemoteSQLConn)
            RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '--------------------------------------------------'
    RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & SchemaName & "." & imTable(0) & _
    " WHERE " & imTable(0) & "_Code = " & "'" & imParam(1) & "'", RemoteSQLConn)
            AbsRecord = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar
            '--------------------------------------------------'
      RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & SchemaName & "." & imTable(1) & " VALUES (newid(), " & AbsRecord & ", CAST('' as varbinary(max)))", RemoteSQLConn)

            RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '--------------------------------------------------'
    RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & imTable(1) & "_Image.PathName() FROM " & _
SchemaName & "." & imTable(1) & " WHERE " & imTable(1) & "_" & imTable(0) & "_ID = " & AbsRecord, RemoteSQLConn)
            Dim filePathName As String = Nothing
            Dim pathObj As Object = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar()
'--------------------------------------------------   Path Name  '
            If Not pathObj.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                filePathName = DirectCast(pathObj, String)
            Else
    Throw New System.Exception("Image.PathName() failed to read the path name for the Image column.")
            End If
    '--------------------------   GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()'
            Dim RemoteSQLtx As SqlTransaction = RemoteSQLConn.BeginTransaction("MainTranaction")
            RemoteSQLcmd.Transaction = RemoteSQLtx
    RemoteSQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()", RemoteSQLConn, RemoteSQLtx)
            Dim tokenObject As Object = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteScalar()
        '--------------------------------------   File Token '
            tokenReader = RemoteSQLcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
            tokenReader.Read()
            Dim txContext As SqlBinary = DirectCast(tokenObject, Byte())
            tokenReader.Close()
            '-----------------------------------------------'
            Try
                '--------------------  Closing all connections'
       If RemoteSQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then RemoteSQLConn.Close()
       If RemoteSQLcmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then RemoteSQLcmd.Connection.Close()
                If RemoteConnInfo.State = ConnectionState.Open Then RemoteConnInfo.Close()
                RemoteSQLtx.Dispose() 
       '---------- Opening all connections for Indegrated Security'
                ChangeLoginPerson("PRINCIDEVEL\Administrator")
                RemoteConnInfo.ConnectionString = "Provider=" & subProvider & "; Data Source=" & subDataSource & _
                "; Database=" & subDataBase & "; Integrated Security=" & "SSPI" & "; Persist Security Info=" & subPSI
                RemoteSQLcmd.Connection.Open()
                RemoteSQLConn = New SqlConnection("Server=" & subDataSource & "; Integrated Security=TRUE" & "; database=" & subDataBase)
                RemoteSQLConn.Open()
                RemoteSQLtx = RemoteSQLConn.BeginTransaction("MainTranaction")
                RemoteSQLcmd.Transaction = RemoteSQLtx
                '-------------------------  Write in to file stream   ---------------'
                Dim imImage As Byte() = New Byte(imStream.Length) {}
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = imStream.Read(imImage, 0, imStream.Length)
                Dim sqlFile As New SqlFileStream(filePathName, txContext, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileOptions.WriteThrough, 0)
                Dim numBytes As Integer = 0
                Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(0)
                While bytesRead > 0
                    sqlFile.Write(imImage, 0, bytesRead)
                    bytesRead = imStream.Read(imImage, 0, imSize)
                End While
                RemoteSQLtx.Commit()
                RemoteSQLcmd.Transaction.Commit()
                sqlFile.Close()
            Catch FsEx As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(FsEx.Message, "Write in SQL File Stream ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Finally
            End Try
            '--------------------------------------------------'
        Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "WriteFileStream ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Finalize()
        Finally
            RemoteSQLConn.Close()
            imStream.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
```